# Unexpected results when learning about inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am learning inheritance and got this problem

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print("test of A called")
class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test of B called")
        super().test()  
class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test of C called")
        super().test()
class D(B,C):
    def test2(self):
        print("test of D called")      
obj=D()
obj.test()
```

The output is below according to the website where this ques was posted

```
test of B called
test of C called
test of A called
```

But in my opinion, the output should be

```
test of B called
test of A called
```

Because, class B will be called first (Acc to MRO), and then `super().test()` is called from class B which will print
`test of A called`.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Google "python mro" - https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order

Comment: The mro for `D` is `(__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: When `B.test` calls `super().test()`, it uses the MRO of the original object. It doesn't just look at `B`'s hierarchy.

Comment: which means first classB will called, then accroding to MRO classC will be called and then classC uses `super` so class A will be called right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know the exact MRO rules off the top of my head, but basically if two classes in the hierarchy have a common base class, the MRO will save that common base class for last.

Comment: Understood, Thanks for the answer. I have accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your code her [http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html][1]  and Visulize line by line. I hope its help.